# Finding events related to a specific feature in a noisy dataset

Tags: correlation

I am working on a tool that has to discover the most likely events related to the presence of a feature.

I have a two dataset containing events. The first contains the observations presenting the feature I am interested into and the other contains the observation that should not be related to the feature.

You can think at my data as a single set of events with attached a FEATURE/NON FEATURE label.

As I mentioned in the comment, an event may appear multiple times in the dataset. Each event represents is discrete and represents a categorical value.

Not all the events labeled with FEATURE actually relates to the feature. They are simply noise due to the fact that I cannot observe the feature in isolation.

Is there any method to find which are the events that are most likely to be specifically related to the feature I am interested into?

I was thinking at some sort of correlation analysis or at a Bayesian analysis but I am not really into statistics and I'd like to have your opinion.

Comment: Perhaps tell us a bit more about your situation. Do you have just one measure per event or observation, or more than one?  Are your data continuous?  Do you consider the data to be interval level? Are any of your data categorical?

Comment: My data comes from execution traces of a program. Part of them are traces obtained by monitoring the execution of the application with a given feature disabled while others tracked the execution of the application with the feature enabled.

An event may occur multiple times in the trace. I am working with categorical discrete data.

Comment: Are there variables that you have at your disposal that tell you that the label is feature or nonfeature.  You need something like that to differentiate the two categories.  Claasification algorithms such as linear discriminant analysis can be used if you have training data (i.e. values for certain variables and their associated categories).  The training data is used to fit the discriminant function that can predict the category based on the values of the variables when the label is unknown.  If the distributions of the variables separate well these algorithms can have low error rates.

Comment: My data is labeled. When I collect the execution traces I know whether they come from the application with the feature enabled or not

Comment: @MichaelChernick is Linear Discriminat Analysis a valid solution to my problem? I have both categorical data and categorical classes

Comment: Linear discriminant analysis would be appropriate if the variables were continuous but classification trees might work for categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is of interest to you, here are two ideas.  First, if just the occurrence of an event is of interest to you, you might do a chi-square.  You have feature or not and you have k events, each present or not.  For example, if you had 2 types of events, you would have a 2x2x2 chi square.  Second, if frequency of the various types of events is of interest to you, you might do a MANOVA with feature or not as the independent variable and the number of occurrences of each of the k types of events as the dependent variables. In either case, assuming you find statistical significance, you could follow up to see which type of event is causing the significance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look for some documentation about the approaches you suggest me.